# Access SQL Can't Create Two Grouped Averages

Tags: sql, ms-access

Apologies for my simple problem, I am an absolute novice. I have the following code in [separate queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14nm6.png)

I am attempting to display 3 columns, the average male salary for a set job, average female salary for a set job and the JobID. Separately these queries work however I cannot work out how to combine them. 
I have tried multiple solutions from this site for example [trying to put multiple select statements inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1J6q.png)
and also by using a 'union' solution however cannot get either to work.[union](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxMWl.png) This simply compiles them into a single column and sorts via salary not JobID.

```
SELECT Round(Avg(Salary)) AS AverageMaleSalary, JobID
FROM Employee WHERE Gender = "M"
GROUP BY JobID;

SELECT Round(Avg(Salary)) AS AverageFemaleSalary, JobID
FROM Employee WHERE Gender = "F"
GROUP BY JobID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT JobId,ROUND(AVG(IIF(Gender='F', Salary, NULL))) AS AverageFemaleSalary
            ,ROUND(AVG(IIF(Gender='M', Salary, NULL))) AS AverageMaleSalary
FROM Employee
GROUP BY JobId;
```

Comment: Thank you, there's a 15 minute timer on the reply so I will make sure to do it when its run out.